# Simple Explanation for Feynman Diagrams

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, education

How would you explain the concept and applications of [Feynman Diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_diagram) to a high school kid?

Comment: Have you tried to read the simple.wikipedia page about feynman diagrams?

Comment: Yes I have, but it is rather non technical. I want a simple but rigorous explanation with some mathematical description and equation :)

Comment: So do you want a simple explanation aimed at a high school level, or do you want rigorous mathematics? The 2 are kind of mutually exclusive.

Comment: @JohnyO42 I would love a high school level proof. Also, I plan to tackle a rigorous mathematical approach after I have completely understood the former!

Comment: I don't think a high school level derivation (or proof) of Feynman diagrams exists, unless you have taken functional analysis and heavy linear algebra in high school.

Comment: @JohnyO42 I would enjoy such a proof. I do have some background into linear algebra and functional analysis ( an heavy olympiad guy :), so)...

Comment: You have accepted an explanation quite unsuitable for a high school student.

Comment: @RobJeffries What do you suggest then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The very basic answer

> A Feynman diagram is a picture representing some sort of interaction between particles. To be redundant it's a diagrammatic representation, following a set of given rules, of a given interaction between particles.

For example, one could think at the following interaction between electrons and positrons $$e^++e^-\to e^++e^-\tag{1}$$ this is called Bhabha scattering, and *one of the possible diagrams* that can picture this interaction is given by the following

[image]

**But why this is useful?** The reality is that every diagram stands really for a complicated formula which is used in the calculation of important quantities like cross sections.

**How do we know the underlying formula?** The cool thing about Feynman diagrams is that all you need to know to build them, and to construct the formula they stand for, is some vary basic building blocks, like legos for particle physicists. These building blocks are encoded in the specific theory one is studying, for the example I gave you the theory is QED (which stands for quantum electrodynamics) which is the theory of the interaction between charged particles.

**So what are these building blocks?** Every theory has essentially the following building blocks: particle/antiparticle lines, propagators and vertices. In the case of QED, the simplest theory one can construct, we have three particles: the electron, the positron (anti-electron) and the photon. From this particles one can construct lines, which are the arrowed external lines in the diagram I gave you as an example, and three propagator, one for each particle. In the Bhabha scattering example the propagator is the one of a photon, the squiggly line. Last but not least, QED has *only one* interaction vertex which is the one where a photon, an electron and an anti-electron meet (in the diagram there are two such vertices). Using all of this we can build up the formula for the amplitude, which is essentially the probability, that the Bhabha interaction $(1)$ happens following the diagram I gave you, and that is the following

$$|A|^2 = \bar{u}(p^\prime)(-ie\gamma^\mu)v(k^\prime)\frac{-ig_{\mu\nu}}{q^2-i\epsilon}\bar{v}(k)(-ie\gamma^\nu)u(p)$$

**What do al these symbols mean?** Well, that's another question and one which cannot be answered easily. If you're interested, you can find the [Feynman rules for QED directly on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_electrodynamics#Feynman_diagrams). As to how these Feynman rules are derived, that's a whole university course and one can do it in many different ways: second quantisation techniques, path integrals and functional quantisation.

**But there is a catch.** For every interaction, such as $(1)$, one can build up practically an infinite amount of diagrams containing more difficult pictures of what's going on. This is due to the fact that in QFT one cannot evaluate some quantities directly and so we rely upon perturbation theory expanding the formula order by order in some parameter (in QED the parameter is the fine structure constant $\alpha$), and to any given order we can attach some Feynman diagrams, for example look at the following [image] And this are only some more complicated diagrams. There are a *lot* more, infinitely many. Going on and on, order by order, gives us a more precise theoretical result that then we can compare with more and more precise experiments.

Then there's the problem of convergence of such expansions, but better not go on this route.

Comment: Moegante Wonderful answer!Just what I was looking for. But, it would be better if I would get a brief description of symbols(just a line would suffice) in the last equation! Thanks anyways!

Comment: @PrateekKulkarni I linked the wikipedia article which lists all the rules and added a little bonus on the perturbative expansion with Feynman diagrams.

Comment: Well that makes it perfect now...love it..thank you very much..!

Comment: @PrateekKulkarni Since you're a new member: If you found that one of the posts answered your question you should accept it. This lets the other members know that the thread is close and gives credit to the user which gave the answer.

Comment: Yep was just about to tick the arrow into green!...

Comment: I disagree that this is a suitable explanation for a high school student.

Comment: @RobJeffries What would you suggest then instead?

Comment: @RobJeffries I would argue that I should have made clearer, with some simple picture, what we actually mean by interaction and so. But i feel that my answer, although lacking most of the specifics, could give a simple picture of what Feynman diagrams are, even for an high school student. In any case, if the OP feels that the answer is not clear or incomplete, I can give more informations or simplify some concepts!

Answer (score 1):

Feynman diagrams are pictorial representations of interactions between particles. It replaces chunks of equations by what we call "Feynman rules": external links that represent entering and outgoing particles, propagators that represent the amplitude for a particle to propagates from a point $x$ to a point $y$ in space-time, and finally vertices that represent the interaction between several particles. In the case of QED, there are two propagators: one for the photon field and one for the electron/positron field. There is one vertex associated with the emission of a photon by an electron (or the absorption of a photon by a positron, or also the annihilation of an electron with a positron that leads to the emission of a photon). Mathematically here is an illustration of how could Feynman diagrams arise from calculating amplitudes of probability:

At the first order of the perturbating theory, the amplitude that represents the creation of an electron-positron pair from a photon is:
\begin{equation}
A_{\sigma,\rho,(n)}=-ie\int d^4x \langle 0| a_\sigma (\vec{k}) b_\rho (\vec{p}) \overline{\Psi}(x^\sigma) \gamma^\mu \Psi (x^\sigma) A_\mu (x^\sigma) \mathfrak{a}^\dagger_{(n)}(\vec{q})|0\rangle.
\end{equation}
Where $e$ is the elementary charge, $\gamma^\mu$ are the Dirac gamma matrices, $\overline{\Psi}$ is the Dirac conjugate of $\Psi$ which is the electron-positron field, $A_\mu$ is the photon field. $\mathfrak{a}^\dagger_{(n)}$ the the operator of creation associated to a photon of polarization $n$, so $\mathfrak{a}^\dagger_{(n)} |0 \rangle$ represents a state with one photon at the beginning. And the same with $\langle 0 | a_\sigma b_\rho$ that is representing a state with one electron of polarization $\sigma$ and one positron with polarization $\rho$ as the final state. Calculating the amplitude gives:
\begin{equation}
A_{\sigma,\rho,(n)}=-ie\gamma^\mu \overline{u}_\sigma(\vec{k}) v_\rho (\vec{p}) e^{(n)}_\mu (2\pi)^4 \delta^{(4)}(k^\nu+p^\nu-q^\nu).
\end{equation}
Where $\overline{u}_\sigma$ is the (Dirac conjugate of the) bispinor of polarization of the electron, $v_\rho$ is the bispinor of polarization of the positron, and $e^{(n)}_\mu$ is the polarization quadri-vector of the photon field. Note that the Dirac delta over the impulsions ensures the conservation of the impulsion.

Here we are : $-ie\gamma^\mu$ is the vertex of the theory, $u_\sigma(\vec{k})$, $v_\rho (\vec{p})$ and $e^{(n)}_\mu$ are its external lines. Calculating the propagators of the theory is more complicated but here is a short path:

Start from the lagrangian density of the theory:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}=-\frac{1}{4} F_{\mu \nu} F^{\mu \nu}+\overline{\Psi}(i\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu-m)\Psi-e\overline{\Psi} \gamma^\mu A_\mu \Psi.
\end{equation}
Where $F_{\mu \nu}$ is the Faraday tensor. Take the differential operator of the fermionic part, $i\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu -m$ and search for its Green function $G$:
\begin{equation}
(i\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu -m)G(x^\nu-y^\nu)=\delta^{(4)}(x^\nu -y^\nu)
\end{equation}
Then, to a $i$ factor and some assumptions about the time ordering of $x^0$ and $y^0$, $G(x^\nu-y^\nu)$ is proportional to the Feynman propagator of the theory. Now for the propagator of the photon part it is a bit more complicated and one has to deal with Feynman path integral and the Faddeev-Popov method, and I will not expose it here because this answer will be too long..

Hope this helped a bit.

Comment: Equally beautiful answer!Thanks a ton...great explanation...

Comment: I'm not sure whether my answer is a good one for a highschool student or not (I was doing all this in my university first year so maybe it's possible for you to understand all of this!)..

Comment: appreciate the effort taken thanks!

Comment: This appears unrelated to the question asked. "Where Fμν is the Faraday tensor. Take the differential operator of the fermionic part, iγμ∂μ−m and search for its Green function G:" for a high school student?